# Programming CC430F5137 using another microcontroller

Tags: programming, msp430, hardware, open-hardware

I have a CC430F5137 and the board schematic all ready for my application to that requires capturing data over bluetooth. I wish to program the CC430F5137 using another platform except the conventional programmer since I'm short of money for the project. Other platforms I have are: Tiva series Launchpad, Stellaris launchpad, MSP430 Launch pad, Arduino, Atmega 32 development board. Please help me by assisting in which to use and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the F5137 supports SBW, then you can use the MSP430 Launchpad as a programmer. Just bring out the two SBW signals plus power and ground to a connector on your board, and connect to J4 on the edge of the Launchpad.

I don't bother with a connector on mine, I use pogo pins to connect to pads underneath the board.